# Domain pointing to VPS not working after changing dns

Tags: dns, vps

I have brought one new VPS(unmanaged VPS) from **[a2hosting.com](https://www.a2hosting.com/)**.

They provide me IP(199.195.116.118) and Nameservers (**dns1.name-services.com** and **dns2.name-services.com**).

My domain is **[omniitworld.com](http://omniitworld.com/)**.

I have changed my domain's dns to **dns1.name-services.com** and **dns2.name-services.com**.

When I check [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) of **omniitworld.com** on **mxtoolbox.com**, it shows **dns1.name-services.com** and **dns2.name-services.com**.
It means my site's [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) is pointed to VPS [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) successfully.

But **omniitworld.com** does not show page I have created on VPS.

Do I have to do any else on VPS or what I have to do now.

Please help in detail.

Comment: Have you created any DNS records there? In any case this is not about programming so is off topic on SO. Server Fault may help you more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DNS lookup of your domain shows that, A record of your domain is pointing to IP address "69.64.147.243", it should be pointing to your VPS IP address, i.e. "199.195.116.118".

https://www.accuwebhosting.com/resources/show-dns-records?q=omniitworld.com

It seems that you are using default nameservers of your registrar, "Enom Incorporated".

To point your domain to VPS, you'll have to change A record to "199.195.116.118".

Following tutorial will help you to achieve this.

http://www.enom.com/kb/kb/kb_0002_change-host-records.htm

Alternatively, you can contact Enom support for the same.